# $compile not compiling ng-href in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

When I pass a template in an attribute, and compile it to render it afther, $compile is working fine except for `ng-href="expression"`, where the expression isn't compiled.

Is this done in the compile function and too late in the link function?

By the way, I link the template scope to it's parent. How can I find the closest scope that is a controllers scope.

`$parent` might not be in all cases the controllers scope.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function(){
  
  var self = this;
  
  self.one = "one";
  self.two = "two";
  
})

.directive('testCompiler', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
      template : '@'
    },
    link : function(scope, element){
      
      var template = angular.element(scope.template);
      var linkFn = $compile(template);
      var child = linkFn(scope.$parent);
      $(element).append(child);
    
    }
  
  
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as AppCtrl">

 <test-compiler template="<div> Hello <span ng-bind='AppCtrl.one'> </span> <a ng-href='AppCtrl.two' ng-bind='AppCtrl.two'> </a> </div>"> </test-compiler>

</div>
```

Comment: Is `self.two = "one";` correct?

Comment: Edited, but has no effect on code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1k023Lhx/ work fine

Comment: No, if you open the console and click on the link, you'll see it's feching `AppCtrl.two` and not `two`

Comment: @gr2g, thx, i saw =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need code like:

```
ng-href='{{AppCtrl.two}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation for the `ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive you will see that it expects a template expression (e.g. `{{propertyOnTheScope}}`):

```
<test-compiler template="<div>Hello <span ng-bind='AppCtrl.one'></span> <a ng-href='{{AppCtrl.two}}' ng-bind='AppCtrl.two'></a></div>">
```

As a side note, this is quite an odd way to pass a template and makes the markup very unclear. I recommend that you look into using a [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

Comment: There is another attribute called array that is expecting an array of object. This array is handled in the directive no matter infinite children all objects have and no matter how much objects there are. It's making a DOM tree you can collapse. In the template you pass in, `item.youObjectKey` is replaced by the object key array and you can add other static information like scope. Those are linked to the controller scope. Any advise how to recognise closest controllers scope?

Comment: @gr3g This sounds off-topic. Please post another question.

Comment: I was describing the purpose because of the side note using transclude